# Should I put @Transactional annotation for submethods also in spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, rollback, transactional

I have a main DB handler method, which calls other methods, which are also working with BD things.

I put @Transactional annotation for the main method, because I want to roll back everything, if something goes wrong.

My question is: should I put this annotation also for the submethods, or it will know that the submethods were called from a method which is transactional.

For example, in the deleting method an exception occurs, how can I make sure that the writing part will be also rollbacked:

```
@Transactional
public void maintDbTings() {
    writing();
    deleting();
}

@Transactional //do I need this?
public void writing() {
    //no exceptions
}

@Transactional //do I need this?
public void deleting() {
    //exception occurs
}
```

Comment: Since those are public and can be called on their own, I suppose you do need the annotation. Just make sure that they aren't creating their own transactions unnecessarily, and use `mainDbThings` transaction if possible.

Comment: but if they would be private, and called only from the main method? will the writing method rolled back if deleting method has exceptions?

Comment: To clarify, you don't need this if the methods are called from mainDbTings, since mainDbTings already starts a transaction if there is one. But then, these methods should be private. If they can be called without going though mainDbTings and should be transactional, then they should also be annotated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring begins a transaction when it encounters a method annotated with `@Transactional`. The transaction’s scope
covers the execution of that method, the execution of any methods that method invokes, and
so on, until the method returns. Any managed resources that are covered by the configured
PlatformTransactionManager and that you use during the transaction scope participate in the
transaction. For example, if you use the `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager`, a Connection retrieved from the linked `DataSource`
participates in the transaction automatically.
The transaction terminates one of two ways: Either the method completes execution directly and the transaction manager commits the transaction, or the method throws an exception and the transaction manager rolls the transaction back.

I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 6):

In plain english, when you have this:

```
@Transactional
public void maintDbTings() {
    writing();
}


@Transactional //do I need this?
public void writing() {
    //no exceptions
}
```

And call **mainDbTings**, the `@Transactional` on the `writing` has no effect. Meaning that the transaction that was started for `mainDbThings` will still be present/open in writing. So in this case you can easily drop it.

On the other hand since `writing` *is public* someone might call it *expecting* it to be transactional, since it is a service class most probably. In this case making `writing` to be `@Transactional` is mandatory and you can't drop it.

So it's up your needs really.

Comment: Also one can use `propagation` property to alter transaction for nested calls. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use propagation properties like REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW, NESTED according to your requirement as described in the below link:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html